# KWIC concordance software

Tags: software-recommendation

I am using UBUNTU trusty Thar. I was searching for a KWIC CONCORDANCE software for indexing and concordance of a book. Can any one help me in finding the software please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look to TextStat http://neon.niederlandistik.fu-berlin.de/en/textstat/
It should do exactly what you're looking for